# Why are my frames so late on android but on pc works fine kivymd

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I got this python app for sending real time frames and kivymd app for receiving those frames, problem is that on android frames are late, and as more time passes they are more late. (When i start app they are late for 1 second, if app is working for 1 minute frames are late for 1 minute).  Also picture is little blue, if anyone know right colorfont that would also help. Here is code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.clock import mainthread
import threading
import socket
import cv2
import pickle
import struct
from datetime import datetime
from kivy import platform

if platform=="android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET])
class Angelus(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.text = "CONNECT"
        self.image = Image(size_hint=(1, 1), pos=(0, 2))
        self.moved_text = self.moved_text3 = self.moved_text4 = self.moved_text5 = self.moved_text6 = 'Did not moved yet'
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        self.label = MDLabel(
            text=self.text,
            adaptive_height=True,
            halign='center', valign='middle'
        )
        layout.add_widget(self.label)
        self.label2 = MDLabel(
            text=self.moved_text,
            adaptive_height=True,
            halign='center', valign='middle'
        )
        self.label3 = MDLabel(
            text=self.moved_text3,
            adaptive_height=True,
            halign='center', valign='middle'
        )
        self.label4 = MDLabel(
            text=self.moved_text4,
            adaptive_height=True,
            halign='center', valign='middle'
        )
        self.label5 = MDLabel(
            text=self.moved_text5,
            adaptive_height=True,
            halign='center', valign='middle'
        )
        self.label6 = MDLabel(
            text=self.moved_text6,
            adaptive_height=True,
            halign='center', valign='middle'
        )
        self.button = MDRaisedButton(
            text="HISTORY",
            on_release=lambda *args: self.show_history(),
            halign='center',
            valign="center"
        )

        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title='History',
            md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.bg_dark,
            size_hint=(0.8, None),
            height=500,
            auto_dismiss=True,
            buttons=[
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text="ClOSE",
                    on_release=lambda *args: self.close()
                ),
            ],
        )

        layout.add_widget(self.button)
        self.i = 1
        self.counter = 0
        self.data = b""
        self.payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
        self.hic = 0
        self.content = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing='12dp', padding='12dp')
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.show_popup(), 0)

        return layout

    def show_history(self):
        self.content = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing='12dp', padding='12dp')
        self.content.add_widget(self.label2)
        self.content.add_widget(self.label3)
        self.content.add_widget(self.label4)
        self.content.add_widget(self.label5)
        self.content.add_widget(self.label6)
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title='History',
            md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.bg_dark,
            size_hint=(0.8, None),
            height=400,
            auto_dismiss=False,
            buttons=[
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text="ClOSE",
                    on_release=lambda *args: self.close()
                ),
            ],
        )
        self.dialog.add_widget(self.content)
        self.dialog.open()
        self.hic = 1

    def close(self):
        self.content.remove_widget(self.label2)
        self.content.remove_widget(self.label3)
        self.content.remove_widget(self.label4)
        self.content.remove_widget(self.label5)
        self.content.remove_widget(self.label6)
        self.dialog.remove_widget(self.content)
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def show_popup(self):
        content = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical', spacing='12dp', padding='12dp')

        text_field = MDTextField(
            size_hint=(0.84, None)
        )
        content.add_widget(text_field)

        dialog = MDDialog(
            title='Enter your IP',
            md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.bg_dark,
            size_hint=(0.8, None),
            height=200,
            auto_dismiss=False,
            buttons=[
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text="CONNECT",
                    on_release=lambda *args: self.on_ok(dialog, text_field.text)
                ),
            ],
        )

        dialog.add_widget(content)
        dialog.open()

    def on_ok(self, dialog, text):
        self.host_ip = text
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.data_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        # self.host_ip = '192.168.1.8'
        self.port = 1055
        self.port2 = 1077
        self.client_socket.connect((self.host_ip, self.port))
        self.data_socket.connect((self.host_ip, self.port2))
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_frame(self.client_socket), 1.0 / 30.0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_data(self.data_socket), 1 / 2)
        dialog.dismiss()

    def update_frame(self, dt):

        while len(self.data) < self.payload_size:
            packet = self.client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
            if not packet: break
            self.data += packet
        packet_msg_size = self.data[:self.payload_size]
        self.data = self.data[self.payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packet_msg_size)[0]

        while len(self.data) < msg_size:
            self.data += self.client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
        frame_data = self.data[:msg_size]
        self.data = self.data[msg_size:]

        frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

        buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='rgb')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture = texture

    def update_data(self, dt):
        data2 = str(self.data_socket.recv(1024).decode())
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        print(data2[0])
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if self.i == 1 and data2[0] == "5":
            self.label2.text = "Moved at: " + current_time
            self.i = 2
        elif self.i == 2 and data2[0] == "5":
            self.label3.text = "Moved at: " + current_time
            self.i = 3
        elif self.i == 3 and data2[0] == "5":
            self.label4.text = "Moved at: " + current_time
            self.i = 4
        elif self.i == 4 and data2[0] == "5":
            self.label5.text = "Moved at: " + current_time
            self.i = 5
        elif self.i == 5 and data2[0] == "5":
            self.label6.text = "Moved at: " + current_time
            self.i = 1
        if self.counter == 1:
            self.label.text = "CONNECTED"
            self.label.size_hint_x = None
            self.label.width = self.label.texture_size[0]
            data2 = []
        elif data2[0] == "5":
            self.label.text = "MOVED AT: " + current_time
            self.label.size_hint_x = None
            self.label.width = self.label.texture_size[0]
            data2 = []


Angelus().run()
```

Python app is fine i tested on various PC-s and WiFi-s, problem only occurs when i run app on android.

Comment: Look into something called lazy loading